# mdadm - not enough to start the array

Tags: mdadm, raid1

I am trying to recover data from a MyBookLiveDuo 3TB*2 RAID1 setup, which is not responding to http/ssh access. I pulled one drive out of the enclosure and attached it via SATA to a Linux laptop. I have run the following.

Dmesg says it is /dev/sdc:

```
[125141.929807] ata4: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[125141.929811] ata4: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[125141.929813] ata4: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[125141.929827] ata4: hard resetting link
[125147.695101] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[125151.729658] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[125151.909228] ata4.00: ATA-9: WDC WD30EZRX-00D8PB0, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
[125151.909231] ata4.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[125151.909888] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[125151.925597] ata4: EH complete
[125151.925652] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EZRX-00D 0A80 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[125151.925828] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[125151.925830] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[125151.925833] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[125151.925971] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[125151.925973] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[125151.925995] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[125152.002603]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4
[125152.003134] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[125152.220477] md: bind<sdc4>
[125152.232731] md: bind<sdc3>
[125152.233892] md/raid1:md126: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
[125152.233912] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 512741376
[125152.234269]  md126: unknown partition table
```

Trying to mount sdc4 directly does not work:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc4 /home/xxx/wdc -t auto
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

Mdstat shows only sdc3 as active, but sdc4 as inactive:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid1] 
md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdc3[2]
      500724 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : inactive sdc4[0](S)
      2925750264 blocks super 1.0

unused devices: <none>
```

Parted shows missing filesystem for sdc4 :

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 3      15.7MB  528MB   513MB                primary  raid
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 4      4624MB  3001GB  2996GB               primary  raid
```

Gdisk "v" (verify) does not find any problems though:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): FA502922-25C1-4759-AAF8-3D1DDA73F5C4
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 31597 sectors (15.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1         1032192         5031935   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   2         5031936         9031679   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   3           30720         1032191   489.0 MiB   FD00  primary
   4         9031680      5860532223   2.7 TiB     FD00  primary

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 31597 free sectors (15.4 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 30686 (15.0 MiB) in size.

Command (? for help): q
```

Trying to assemble and scan only shows /dev/sdc3 as active:

```
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md12[567]
mdadm: stopped /dev/md126
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid1] 
unused devices: <none>
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/MyBookLiveDuo:3 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: /dev/md/MyBookLiveDuo:2 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
mdadm: /dev/md/MyBookLiveDuo:3 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid1] 
md127 : active raid1 sdc3[2]
      500724 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

E2fsck says bad magic number in super-block:

```
$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc3
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdc3 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc4
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc4

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

$
```

Trying to mount md127 thinks it is NTFS ???

```
$ sudo mount /dev/md127 /home/xxx/wdc -t auto
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md127': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md127' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed further to be able to mount /dev/sdc4 and recover data ?

**EDIT 1:**
 Output from examine sdc4 is below. It says RAID level = linear.

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 374e689e:3bfd050c:ab0b0dce:2d50f5fd
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:3
  Creation Time : Mon Sep 16 14:53:47 2013
     Raid Level : linear
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 5851500528 (2790.21 GiB 2995.97 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 0
   Super Offset : 5851500528 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9096f74b:0a8f2b61:93347be3:6d3b6c1b

    Update Time : Mon Sep 16 14:53:47 2013
       Checksum : 77aa5963 - correct
         Events : 0

       Rounding : 0K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Output from examine sdc3 is below, which mdstat says is active. It says RAID level = RAID1.

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 7c040c5e:9c30ac6d:e534a129:20457e22
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:2
  Creation Time : Wed Dec 31 19:01:40 1969
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1001448 (489.07 MiB 512.74 MB)
     Array Size : 500724 (489.07 MiB 512.74 MB)
   Super Offset : 1001456 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1d9fe3e3:d5ac7387:d9ededba:88ca24a5

    Update Time : Sun Jul  3 11:53:31 2016
       Checksum : 31589560 - correct
         Events : 101


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdc3[2]
      500724 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : inactive sdc4[0](S)
      2925750264 blocks super 1.0

unused devices: <none>
```

And partitions is:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 1953514584 sda
   8        1     102400 sda1
   8        2 1953411072 sda2
   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17     248832 sdb1
   8       18          1 sdb2
   8       21 1953263616 sdb5
 252        0 1953261568 dm-0
 252        1 1919635456 dm-1
 252        2   33488896 dm-2
   8       32 2930266584 sdc
   8       33    1999872 sdc1
   8       34    1999872 sdc2
   8       35     500736 sdc3
   8       36 2925750272 sdc4
   9      126     500724 md126
```

**EDIT 2: (Different RAID disk from another enclosure)**

Using a good disk from a different WDLiveDuo enclosure, which is configured in same RAID1 way (2*3TB disks), the output of examine for sdc3 and sdc4 shows that both have RAID level = RAID1. So, for the bad disk listed **above**, sdc3 shows correct RAID level = RAID1, but somehow, sdc4 does not have the correct RAID level configured. Is there a way to change/fix the RAID level to be RAID1 and then will it allow me to load it and get data out of the bad disk ?

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : inactive sdc4[2](S)
      2925750136 blocks super 1.0

md127 : inactive sdc3[1](S)
      500724 blocks super 1.0

unused devices: <none>
$
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 1953514584 sda
   8        1     102400 sda1
   8        2 1953411072 sda2
   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17     248832 sdb1
   8       18          1 sdb2
   8       21 1953263616 sdb5
 252        0 1953261568 dm-0
 252        1 1919635456 dm-1
 252        2   33488896 dm-2
   8       32 2930266584 sdc
   8       33    1999872 sdc1
   8       34    1999872 sdc2
   8       35     500736 sdc3
   8       36 2925750272 sdc4
$
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 7c040c5e:9c30ac6d:e534a129:20457e22
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:2
  Creation Time : Wed Dec 31 19:01:40 1969
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1001448 (489.07 MiB 512.74 MB)
     Array Size : 500724 (489.07 MiB 512.74 MB)
   Super Offset : 1001456 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e0963cfc:7ba16214:94e24c90:32988d39

    Update Time : Mon Jul  4 13:20:48 2016
       Checksum : 412bab99 - correct
         Events : 288


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
$
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ac48cc98:1d450838:dd0b0364:61b3168e
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:3
  Creation Time : Sat Jul  2 19:57:43 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 5851500272 (2790.21 GiB 2995.97 GB)
     Array Size : 2925750136 (2790.21 GiB 2995.97 GB)
   Super Offset : 5851500528 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1233b655:2f5fd745:c1c71658:f05af045

    Update Time : Mon Jul  4 13:21:15 2016
       Checksum : b83b08dc - correct
         Events : 54432


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
$
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md12[567]
mdadm: stopped /dev/md126
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
$
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/MyBookLiveDuo:3 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
mdadm: /dev/md/MyBookLiveDuo:2 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
$
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdc3[1]
      500724 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : active raid1 sdc4[2]
      2925750136 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
$
$ sudo parted -l /dev/sdc
Model: ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 3      15.7MB  528MB   513MB                primary  raid
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 4      4624MB  3001GB  2996GB  ext4         primary  raid
Error: /dev/md126: unrecognised disk label                                

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md127: 2996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2996GB  2996GB  ext4
$
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): BDE03D26-EB85-4348-A4E0-A229FC01EE93
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 31597 sectors (15.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1         1032192         5031935   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   2         5031936         9031679   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   3           30720         1032191   489.0 MiB   FD00  primary
   4         9031680      5860532223   2.7 TiB     FD00  primary

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 31597 free sectors (15.4 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 30686 (15.0 MiB) in size.

Command (? for help): q
$
$ sudo mount /dev/md127 /home/xxx/wdc -t ext4
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc4`

Comment: @Patrick I have added the output of examine in EDIT 1 above.

Answer (score 1):

The `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc4` output shows why the raid device is not coming online:

```
 Raid Level : linear
```

A linear-raid device needs all the devices in the RAID group to be able to start up.

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#Linear_mode

Comment: The other disk that was part of RAID1, is physically not responding i.e. even if I connect it, the device does not show up. So, I am trying to figure out how to get the data out of this disk that is responding. Is there some configuration change that I can make to this disk, which will allow me to get the data out of the disk ?

Comment: No. If you don't have all the disks in the raid group, the data is lost. See the link I provided: "If a disk dies, the array dies with it".

Comment: So, Using a good disk from a different WDLiveDuo enclosure, which is configured in same RAID1 way (2*3TB disks), the output of examine for sdc3 and sdc4 shows that both have RAID level = RAID1. So, for the bad disk listed above, sdc3 shows correct RAID level = RAID1, but somehow, sdc4 does not have the correct RAID level configured. Is there a way to change/fix the RAID level to be RAID1 and then will it allow me to load it and get data out of the bad disk ? Interestingly, I still cannot mount /dev/md127 using -t ext4.

Comment: No. You cannot just change the raid type and have your data magically come back. The data is straight up missing. There's nothing you can do unless you get that missing disk working.

Comment: Ok, one last question. Why am I not able to mount /dev/md127 from the good disk from different enclosure?

Comment: Update: Searching about this little more, I found the free r-linux tool, which does a low level disk scan, with known file types. It is able to find lot/most files on disk, but misses the folder information. So, files do exist on disk. I am now reading more about filesystems, superblocks, inodes etc. to see if I can recover folder structure.