# Recover Synology JBOD disk in Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm

I know there are already many topics about this but none of these work for me because I have many different problems. I got a 18TB hard drive that I was running in a Synology. Now I want to use it in Unraid but need to copy all of the data to another hard drive. I cannot mount it because it tells me `unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'`.

So I created an Ubuntu VM in Unraid and passthrough my disk. But no matter what I do I cannot mount the drive. Tried several tutorial like this: https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC

`cat /proc/mdstat` output:

```
md3 : inactive sda3[0](S)
      17573506048 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

`lvs` output:

```
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 28.47g
```

`lsblk` output (sda is the hard drive):

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1822
loop1                       7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                       7:2    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
sda                         8:0    0  16.4T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   2.4G  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part
└─sda3                      8:3    0  16.4T  0 part
  └─md3                     9:3    0     0B  0 md
sr0                        11:0    1   1.8G  0 rom
vda                       252:0    0    60G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─vda2                    252:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0  56.9G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  28.5G  0 lvm  /
```

If I try to do something like `sudo mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md3 /dev/sda3` I get the following output (Unknown keyword INACTIVE-ARRAY is a result of some commands that I tried):

```
mdadm: Unknown keyword INACTIVE-ARRAY
mdadm: Unknown keyword INACTIVE-ARRAY
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is busy - skipping
```

`/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` content:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.2 UUID=9a85c15e:c7bdb277:6b73dd56:eb13ce56 name=Backup-NAS:3
/dev/md127 metadata=1.2 name=Backup-NAS:3 UUID=9a85c15e:c7bdb277:6b73dd56:eb13ce56
/dev/md3 metadata=1.2 name=Backup-NAS:3 UUID=9a85c15e:c7bdb277:6b73dd56:eb13ce56
```

The first entry was there and the others were generated by using `mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

I've added this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/md3 /media/storage ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
```

I have no idea what to do. No matter what I try md3 stays inactive and I cannot mount because the device is busy. I can also create a fresh VM if it would help.

Comment: Try `mdadm --run /dev/md3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the end that the RAID was linear. I had to add the second drive: [mdadm - not enough to start the array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293613/mdadm-not-enough-to-start-the-array)

It worked instantly.